# How do I get the color scheme in MS Flow or Logic Apps?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm building a little solution to describe image files uploaded to picture libraries, and this could be based on MS Flow or Logic Apps, the problem I'm having is to get the color scheme from the image, none of the available connectors is returning the information about colors in the images (something like the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-detecting-color-scheme)

So how do I build a Flow or a Logic App using Computer Vision? Do I need to code anything like an special REST call for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In logic App , you can just use a http action to call Computer Vision APIs to get color scheme as below :
[image]

Result :

[image]

If you have anyfurther concerns , pls feel free to let me know.